# Adding empty rows above a cell depending on its value

Tags: excel

In column A, I have the string 'new height' in cells at fixed intervals: `A1`, `A5803`, `A11605` and so on, every 5802 rows.

I want to add 2391 empty rows above each cell containing the string 'new height'.

Comment: Have you considered a VBA macro ? You can record the actions and implement it this way. I would start by checking this link as a start point. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from Olly on excel-forum and it works-

```
Sub foo()
    Const lRows As Long = 2391
    Const sText As String = "new height"

    Dim s() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:A").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=sText
        s = Split(.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address, ",")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        For i = UBound(s) To LBound(s) Step -1
            .Range(s(i)).Resize(lRows, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```